# Python press key down until another key

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui, pynput

I've already looked at previous post, but can't find something that works...

Globally my goal : a script in python that if I press ‘k’ it will start to hold ‘k’ until I press escape. 
But the problem is : it doesn’t hold ‘k’ and I don’t know why

If someone might help I’d be glad,
Thank you

```py
from pynput import keyboard
import pyautogui

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
        if key.char == 'k':
            return False
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def listening_k():
    with keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
    return True

def listening_esc():
    with keyboard.Listener(
            on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
    return True


def hold_key(key):
    while listening_k() == True :
        pyautogui.keyDown(key)
        if listening_esc() == True :
            break

hold_key('k')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple by having a variable that holds the state (boolean value) if 'k' key is on press. Make it True anytime you press 'k' key and False for pressing 'esc' key.

Comment: But the problem is, when I call the listening_k() it won't stop listening (so doing nothing else) until the 'k' is pressed, and when I call listening_esc() it will do the same thing